# Clearing doctrine's mapping cache

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I mistakenly used a mysql reserved keyword 'condition' when defining my model(yml). I then renamed the field to 'description' and generated entities but cannot run the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` because the generated query `ALTER TABLE segment_filters CHANGE condition description VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL`  contains the keyword.

I have tried the following:

- renaming field directly on the database(desparation)
- clearing cache `php app/console  cache:clear`
- clearing various doctrine caches `doctrine:cache:clear-* -flush` (with and without flush)

I have tried googling and reading but maybe it's one of those days that the head just needs a break. Any help will be heavily appreciated

Comment: Your web server may have cached them. Try rebooting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue before. This is related to mysql syntax. Symfony2 reverse engineering will help you resolve this issue

1. Change the col name directly on the database table.
2. run php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force Bundlename format(yml/xml/php).

This will map your doctrine yml's for that bundle with the database

3. run doctrine:generate:entities on that bundle.

Mission accomplished.